# Oracle/SQL - Select records on at specific sysdate times

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a query that runs multiple times a day, the issue though is we want the query to **only** return result when it's run at certain times.  So for this example I only want records to be returned when the query is run during the 8am hour.  I thought this might work

```
case
    when to_char(sysdate,'HH24') = '08' then
        select
            *
        from
            tablename
end
```

And indeed it does during the 8am hour, but outside of that it errors rather than returning no records.

Any ideas?

---

Okay well that was dumb of me.  I was WAY over thinking it.  I was stuck on having to use a if then sort of condition.  Time for more coffee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
    select
        *
    from
        tablename
    where 
        to_char(sysdate,'HH24') = '08';
```

Comment: Apologies for the over thinking and ridiculous question :D

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM tablename
 WHERE to_char( sysdate, 'HH24' ) = '08'
```

Comment: Apologies for the over thinking and ridiculous question :D